# Marshalling XML in GOlang: field is empty (APPEND doesn't work?)

Tags: xml, go

i'm learning to create XML in Go. Here's my code:

```
type Request struct {
    XMLName       xml.Name        `xml:"request"`
    Action        string          `xml:"action,attr"`
    ...
    Point         []point         `xml:"point,omitempty"`
}

type point struct {
    geo    string `xml:"point"`
    radius int    `xml:"radius,attr"`
}

func main() {
    v := &Request{Action: "get-objects"}
    v.Point = append(v.Point, point{geo: "55.703038, 37.554457", radius: 10})
    output, err := xml.MarshalIndent(v, "  ", "    ")
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("error: %v\n", err)
    }
    os.Stdout.Write([]byte(xml.Header))
    os.Stdout.Write(output)

}
```

I expect the output to be like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <request action="get-objects">
      <point radius=10>55.703038, 37.554457</point>
  </request>
```

But what I'm getting is:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
      <request action="get-objects">
          <point></point>
      </request>
```

What am I missing or doing wrong?
Because the "name,attr" thing works perfect for everything else (for example, for the "request" field, as you can see). 
Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Several things are wrong in your code. When working with encoding packages in Go, all the fields you want to marshal/unmarshal have to be exported. Note that the structs themselves do not have to be exported.

So, first step is to change the `point` struct to export the fields:

```
type point struct {
    Geo    string `xml:"point"`
    Radius int    `xml:"radius,attr"`
}
```

Now, if you want to display the `Geo` field inside a point, you have to add `,cdata` to the xml tag. Finally, there is no need to add an `omitempty` keyword to a slice.

```
type Request struct {
    XMLName xml.Name `xml:"request"`
    Action  string   `xml:"action,attr"`
    Point   []point  `xml:"point"`
}

type point struct {
    Geo    string `xml:",chardata"`
    Radius int    `xml:"radius,attr"`
}
```

[Go playground](https://play.golang.org/p/9pGMl570Q0)

Comment: Thank you so much! And thanks for pointing to other mistakes.

Answer (score 2):

The members that you want to marshal have to be exported (capitalized). Try:

```
type point struct {
    Geo    string `xml:"point"`
    Radius int    `xml:"radius,attr"`
}
```

From the [`encoding/xml` doc](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/xml/):

> The XML element for a struct contains marshalled elements **for each of
>   the exported fields of the struct**.
>
> [..]
>
> Because Unmarshal uses the reflect package, **it can only assign to
>   exported (upper case) fields**.